# Date composition from day, month and year input

Tags: javascript, datetime

I need to concatenate 3 input fields into a string which is formatted as a date `dd-mm-yyyy`, using `type="date"` or `new Date()` will not work in my scenario because Firebase doesn't allow it for some reason. I came up with a rather ugly solution, but I'm not quite sure how to improve it. `delete` is bad for performance, but I think that it is needed because I need to completely remove the properties from the object once they've been used.

```
$scope.addWeek = function(week) {

  var startDate = '' + week.startDate.day + '-' + week.startDate.month + '-' + week.startDate.year,
      endDate = '' + week.endDate.day + '-' + week.endDate.month + '-' + week.endDate.year;

  week.startDate = startDate;
  week.endDate = endDate;

  delete week.startDate.day;
  delete week.startDate.month;
  delete week.startDate.year;
  delete week.endDate.day;
  delete week.endDate.month;
  delete week.endDate.year;
}
```

The week object looks like this:

```
week = {
  number: 32,
  startDate: {
    day: 01,
    month: 07,
    year: 2015
  },
  endDate: {
    day: 08,
    month: 09,
    year: 2016
  }
}
```

After we're done it needs to look like this:

```
week = {
  number: 32,
  startDate: 01-07-2015,
  endDate: 08-09-2016
}
```

Any suggestions on how to improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ekkhard.Homer said, none of you `delete` lines do anything, because `startDate` and `endDate` are strings at that point: They don't have any `day`, `month` or `year` properties.

Anyway, since you need to do the same thing twice, I'd suggest you make a function for it. I've spruced this one up a bit by mapping properties, but that's not really necessary.

```
$scope.addWeek = function(week) {

  function formatDate(obj) {
    return ['day', 'month', 'year'].map(function (prop) {
      return String(obj[prop]);
    }).join('-');
  }

  week.startDate = formatDate(week.startDate);
  week.endDate = formatDate(week.endDate);
}
```

Comment: Haha man I didn't even realise that I was overriding them. This is a good solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this:

```
function parseDate(input) {
  var str= input.split('/');
  return new Date(str[0], str[1]-1, str[2]); 
}
```

`str[1]-1` as months starts from 0.

You may also check [`Date.parse(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) but this is implementation dependent.

Comment: I think you got it backward. The code is not about parsing a string; it's about _formatting_ a string. The _output_ should be `dd-mm-yyyy`, not the input.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense at all to do something with 'week.startDate.day' (etc) **after** you assigned a string to `week.startDate`.